# execute the "getAddress(geoLng,geoLat);" NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

why does

```
getAddress(geoLng,geoLat);
address = coder.getFromLocation(mlat, mLon, 3);
```

gives me this exception

```
07-27 00:21:14.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1228): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Below is the code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null) {
        Double geoLat = location.getLatitude();
        Double geoLng = location.getLongitude();
        String str = ("location:(" + geoLng + "," + geoLat + ")");


        getAddress(geoLng,geoLat);

    }
}
//
public void getAddress(final double mlat, final double mLon) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                address = coder.getFromLocation(mlat, mLon, 3);
                if (address != null || address.size() > 0) {

                    /*handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler,
                            Constants.GEOCODER_RESULT));*/

                }

        }catch (AMapException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            handler.sendMessage(Message
                    .obtain(handler, Constants.ERROR));

    }}});

    t.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough code here to give a full answer, but did you actually initialize coder?  If it is failing on that line, then the only way is if coder was null.

Comment: Interrupted point at  "getAddress(geoLng,geoLat);"  go to Double.class. It should go to the method of getAddress().why?